# Set selection options depending on another select element's value in Angular

Tags: angular

I have this 2 `select` tags. I want that when choose a `selectedClass` only show the students of that class.

```
  <div class="col-md-2 mb-3">
      <h3>Turma</h3>
      <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedClass" name="class">
        <option [ngValue]="cl" *ngFor="let cl of classes">{{cl.year}} - {{cl.class}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5 mb-3">
      <h3>Aluno</h3>
      <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedStudent" name="student">
        <option [ngValue]="st" *ngFor="let st of students">{{st.name}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend you use reactive forms, but in this case you should declare change event function, like:

```
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedClass" name="class" (ngModelChange)="classChanged($event)">
...
```

And declare this function in your component:

```
classChanged(newVal: any) {
  ...// parse your changed value
  this.students = ... // array you need
}
```

Same for the students.